# Add new page with new Component in DXA example site

Tags: dxa

I installed DXA example site successfuly and can edit existing Entities.

To move it further, I want to create my own Schema, Component, Page Template and display it in the DXA example site.

What I did are:

1. Create a new Schema, named **MyItem**, with two plain text fields **Name** and **Description**;
2. Create a new Component Template, exactly the same as **Article** Template, just renamed it to **MyItem**
3. Go to the DxaWebApp, add a new folder **Models** under **Core** folder, then add a new class `MyItem.cs`, like below:

   ```
   [SemanticEntity(Vocab = "http://schema.org", EntityName = "ShopItem", Prefix = "s", Public = true)]
   public class MyItem : EntityModel
   {
       [SemanticProperty("s:name")]
       public string Name { get; set; }

       [SemanticProperty("s:description")]
       public string Description { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. Add a new file `MyItem.cshtml` in the folder **Entity**, with below code:

   ```
   @model Sdl.Web.Site.Areas.Core.Models.ShopItem
   @Model.Name
   @Model.Description
   ```
5. Add a new page `MyItemPage.cshtml` under **Page** folder. Content is exactly the same as `GeneralPage.cshtml`
6. Create the new Page in CMS, attach the **MyItem** Component to it;

After that update the Navigation and refresh setting then publish the Page. I can see the new Page name be displayed in the portal navigation, and it will load the `MyItemPage.cshtml` view. But there is no content be displayed in the page. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read the DXA documentation?
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v5/GUID-51433BAF-438D-4E54-B1C2-DA390D2DE729

I have a few remarks on the points you mention:

1. Schema.org does not define a type ShopItem, so your SemanticEntity attribute is not correct. That is not relevant for the model mapping though; implicit mapping will work if you ensure your Schema's Root Element Name is the same as your View Model class name (`MyItem`).
2. Check the metadata on your CT. Normally, the MVC data (e.g. View name) is specified there and in that case CT title is not relevant.
3. Don't forget to also register your View Model (and associated View) in the Area Registration.
4. Remarkably minimalistic View. :-)
5. `MyItemPage.cshtml` is not a Page, but a Page View (used for all Pages based on an associated Page Template). You don't have to create your own Page View right away, but if you do you have to Register it and have an associated PT.

Comment: The issue was solved. The CT metadata didn't contain the correct view name is the main reason why it couldn't work. Thanks for your help.